# Git: Merge staged file with the one in working tree

Tags: git

I have a file named `foo`. I make some modification `M1` to `foo` and stage it. Then I revert it in the working tree by checking it out from `HEAD`, and make another modification `M2` to it. Now I want to merge these two modifications before commit. How can this be done? Thanks!

(I know branches are for this kind of work. But I'd like to know whether there is a way to merge a staged file with the modified version in the working tree.)

Comment: How are you checking out with unstaged changes?

Comment: I don't have unstaged changes. As I mentioned, I've staged `M1` before the checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to create two commits, and merge them. This is fairly safe, as once you get your changes into two different commits, it's fairly hard to lose them, and if the merge doesn't go as you want, you can throw away the merge commit and try again.

For the first commit, you already have the changes staged, so just `git commit` should be sufficient.

For the second, you have a state in your working copy that represents changes to the original `HEAD`. But now that you've done that commit, there's an intervening one; `HEAD` is what was in the index, so it looks like your working copy reverts those changes. To get around this, we need to reset where our `HEAD` points, without changing what's in the working copy.

Before doing so, let's save a pointer to our current `HEAD`: `git branch was-in-index`. Now we can reset to the previous `HEAD` (the parent of `HEAD`) with `git reset HEAD^`, and add and commit our changes `git add some stuff; git commit` (or `git commit -a`, if you want all of your changes).

Now we have two branches; our current one, which contains the changes from the working copy, and `was-in-index`, which contains the changes which were in the index. Now you can merge these however you want; `git merge was-in-index`, `git rebase was-in-index`, or what have you. You can delete the `was-in-index` branch when you're done.

Comment: This is a fairly standard solution. Well, I want to merge index with working tree because it saves all these work. You stage M1 and later merge it back, very lightweight and good for small modifications. But your answer is detailed and excellent. Accepted.

Comment: check out mine with stash. I think it's more what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to stash:

```
# modify file
git stash -u
# modify file in a different way
git add -A && git commit -m "M2"
git stash pop
# resolve conflicts
git add -A && git commit --amend -m "M1 and M2 merged"
```

no branches to deal with.

Comment: A super clever solution. I love this no-branch solution. The log is much cleaner than the branch-and-merge method if you save modifications in stash rather than branch. It's very close to what I want. It's just that I've promised to accept another one...But a vote-up is given, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is a 4-step process.

1. `git commit` the staged changes to foo.
2. modify foo, adding M2 on top of M1
3. `git add foo`, putting M2 in the staging area.
4. `git commit --amend`, merging M1 with M2.

This isn't exactly what you asked, but I believe that it's the most efficient way to get the outcome you're requesting.

Comment: This won't actually merge the changes. If I have a change staged which replaces `foo` with `bar`, and the change in my working copy adds a function `zot` (but does not contain the `foo` to `bar` change), then once I commit my change, it will look like my working copy reverts the `foo` to `bar` rename and adds `zot`, and the `git commit --amend` will happily squash that revert into the original commit, obliterating it, rather than merging those two changes like was asked for.

Comment: Hmm, I think my answer was misleading - I was assuming there wasn't a reset of state to the file in between the commit and the add. I've clarified my answer, which I don't believe suffers from the problem you've correctly pointed out.